# Assembly mov with location stored in variable

Tags: assembly, nasm, intel

I'm using nasm for an intel processor, just to inform you about my situation.

So here is my problem:

I got a variable named pos which should store a memory adress like 3998 or something like this. Now I want to make a move to the adress stored in this var. How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Thats my code right now:

```
mov ax, 0xb800 ; Go to the adress of the video card
mov ds, ax

printloop:
    cmp [pos], byte 0 ; check if the value stored in pos is not  0
    je hang
    mov [pos], byte 36 ; PROBLEM: what it should do: write the ascii symbol(here $) to the position stored in pos
    sub [pos], byte 2 ; decrement address stored in pos by two
    jmp printloop

hang: ; just a hang loop when all is done
    jmp hang

pos db 3998 ; the var pos with the initialization address 3998, which is the down right corner
```

Is it possible with a var? Or do I have to use a register? How do I do it then?

Thanks for all responses.

Comment: You can't fit 3998 in a byte.

Comment: So, it works good, when i decrement pos by 6 everytime. Then it fills everything with a cool pattern. When changing it back to 2 it stops before it colors everything. It just doesn't change till the end. I found out, that when I increment ax to for example 0xb8aa it ends filling it earlier. So it looks like, the ax position changes where the filling ends, but only when decrementing pos by two everytime. I cannot make ax lower than b800, because it's not inside the graphics bounds. Is it my mistake or a hardware "problem"? Or should I change ds to a lower number? Thanks for help :)

Comment: Don't re-use a question to post new questions. If you have a new question, post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is use indirect addressing through a register:

```
mov bx, [pos]
mov byte [bx], 36
```

You will also want to use `dw` instead of `db` to define `pos` because 3998 is too large a value for a single byte.

Comment: Since the OP is using nasm, appears to be writing real-mode code, and has declared `pos` as a byte, I think he needs something like `movzx bx,byte [pos]` / `mov byte [bx],36`

Comment: Oh, my bad, my fingers type `ebx` by default. :)

Comment: Let me interpret this: We move the value of pos to ebx. Correct? Then we actual move the $ to the location. What does the word ptr do? Does it "convert" the number to an address?

Comment: The `ptr` was masm syntax, sorry I've edited that out since you don't need it. The `byte [bx]` tells the assembler to generate a byte move instruction, otherwise it doesn't know how much data you actually want to move (after all, it could be 36 as a word).

Comment: @GregHewgill: You still need brackets on the first line. Otherwise you get the address of `pos` instead of the value at `pos`.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. Now I remember why I don't bother to write asm code any longer. :)

Comment: @Michael movzx extends the value by zeroes? leading or trailing? And  another question: Whats the difference between registers with leading e an these without?

Comment: @GregHewgill I don't want to use the language longer then I need, but as you could see in my other question I'm trying to code a little OS :D

Comment: @Michael right now I'm in real mode. Does it get harder when I'm in protected mode?

Comment: For application developers I'd say it's generally a lot nicer to be in protected mode. For OS developers I've no idea.

Comment: :D I just want to test a bit, if I understood how it works. When I read something I don't really understand it. I have to modify it and look what changes. Right now It looks better than before, but I got another problem: It doesn't show the $ from one corner to the other. It starts in the mid... Thats strange I think...

Comment: Not so strange. Text mode uses two bytes for each character - one for the character (ascii code) and one for the color. I'm surprised you're finding `pos` after altering `ds`!

Comment: So I understood it right: When I write for example
     mov byte [bx], 0x2123
Then it writes the ASCII code character 23 whats # with the color 21. Correct? I had a site where the colors were explained, but I can't find it anymore :D @FrankKotler what should I do instead? When not modifying ds it does not even write something...

Comment: Thought its solved, but it isnt. When Im setting pos to 3998 it prints the char somewhere in the middle and not in the corner. Do I have to use another number?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is, if we are in the real mode, or in the v86-mode, the segment size is limited to 64 KB and so we can not use the same segment address of DS for to address the location of the pos label outside the framebuffer and additional for to address an another location but inside the framebuffer.

One solution is to use a second segment register, one segment register for to address the framebuffer and the other one for to address the location of the pos label. (@Frank Kotler: I always like to take a notice of your expertise.)

```
mov ax, 0xb800 ; segment address of the framebuffer
mov es, ax     ; store it into the ES segment register

; not shown here,but with a DOS *.exe file we default use a separated DATA-segment
; DS=CS if the label of pos is placed inside of our codesegment
; (not needed if running as a DOS *.COM file)
mov ax, cs     ; get the segment address of the code segment
mov ds, ax     ; store it into the DS segment register

printloop:
cmp [pos], byte 0 ; check if the value stored in DS:pos is not  0
je hang
mov di, [pos]     ; get the offset address stored in DS:pos
mov es:[di], byte 36 ; write the ascii symbol to the position stored in es:di
sub [pos], byte 2 ; decrement address stored in DS:pos by two
jmp printloop

hang: ; just a hang loop when all is done
jmp hang

pos dw 3998 ; the (16 bit) offset address 3998, which is the down right corner
```

It is also possible to place the instruction for to get the offset address above the loop (only need this instruction one times) and to decrease the DI register and to compare the DI register inside the loop instead and in substitution of to decrease and to check the content of pos.

Comment: Compiling it gives me an invalid combination of opcode and operands error in this line:
    mov es:[di], byte 36

Has the complete es:[di] also has to be in brackets like that: [es:[di]] ?